# Security issue in 0x in-chain example

Tags: security, 0x

I was going through 0x on-chain docs and I saw the official example [here](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api-starter-guide-code/blob/900a3264847c81aa75070fc43c996b2012402597/contracts/SimpleTokenSwap.sol#L65) which calls an arbitrary contract `swapTarget` whose address is given as a parameter. It seems a huge security pitfall, as it can be exploited by a bad actor using an attacking contract passed as `swapTarget` parameter.
Is there a proper way to obtain the `swapTarget` address, apart from calling the 0x API directly from the contract itself via Chainlink AnyAPI service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target is currently always the same, so you can just use a whitelist.